# Index.js module imports with webpack

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-module-loader

My code is organised as follows:

[image: Folder hierarchy]

where,

Resources/ActionLog/Components/Layout.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Test</p>
        );
    }
}
```

Resources/ActionLog/Components/index.js

```
export * from './Layout';
```

Resources/ActionLog/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Layout from './Components'; // <--- ISSUE HERE.

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
    <Layout/>,
    app
);
```

Why does `Layout` not get imported using this setup??

If i change the line to read,

`import Layout from './Components/Layout';`

it works fine, but otherwise `Layout` is always undefined! Even when if i try,

`import Layout from './Components/index';`

I am using webpack as my module bundler, and have achieved something similar before, I just don't see why/how this is different..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does Layout not get imported using this setup??

`Layout.js` has a *default* export. However, `export * from './Layout.js` will only export the *named* exports (of which there are none). In other words, `Components/Layout.js` doesn't have any exports at all, so nothing can be imported.

But even if it did have named exports, `import Layout from './Components/index';` imports the *default* export, but `Components/index.js` doesn't have a default export.

---

There are a couple of ways this could be solved. The one that makes the most sense is probably to export the default export of `Layout.js` as named export in `Components/index.js`. You will presumably have multiple files each exporting a component. I assume `Components/index.js` should export a map of all these components in which case you have to use named exports.

The changes you have to make:

```
// in Components/index.js
export {default as Layout} from './Layout';


// in ActionLog/index.js
import {Layout} from './Components'; // use a named import
```

Comment: You, kind sir, are a godsend. Cheers for this, I guess I still need to brush up on my ES6.